# How does window.innerHeight handle rounding?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where I want to use the height of the window to restrict my use of rangeForCoordinates(). Example:

```
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
var test = rangeForCoordinates(x, windowHeight-1);
```

I found a few android phones where the screen density causes rounding, example:

```
// device screen density: 1.33
// webview height in pixels: 610 pixels
// window.innerHeight gives me: 459 
//  (610 / 1.33) = 458.64... and rounded up
```

Now if I try using that height as the ceiling, I'll get an intersected element that doesn't make any sense:

```
// incorrect element returned
var test = rangeForCoordinates(x, 459-1);
```

If I instead use the floor'd instead of rounded value, it works fine:

```
// ok
var test = rangeForCoordinates(x, 458-1);
```

Is there a way to get the height of the window without this rounding applied? It looks like 459 is out of bounds.

I was hoping that rangeForCoordinates() would return null if given out of bounds coordinates, but looks like that's not the case on some devices.

Thanks

Comment: Every browser (literally), not just mobile, has it's own way of interpreting JavaScript and CSS that are for the most part, sort of the same.You must have rounding, otherwise how, if you are not using Math.floor() or Math.ceil(), would you work out 3px * 0.5? You can't (shouldn't) have half pixels, they should be an integer. Some browsers move it up, others round down. If it's that important, do it yourself with ceil() or floor() and compensate accordingly.

Comment: The pixel ratio is not really a float : here 1.33 means 4/3, meaning there's 4 backing pixels every 3 pixels. Maybe computing this way is safer.

Comment: Yeah for some reason I thought they would all do it the same way. Is there a way to get the height of the window in device pixels so I can do the rounding myself?